# Socrata does it support startswith or endswidth on a column

Tags: socrata

Currently socrata only supports 
https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv?region=Victoria Islands region&source=pr

Is there an option to find the region's StartsWith Victoria?

Answer (score 1):

We do not have a direct startsWith function but there are ways to derive the same results. Try https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$q=Victoria. Note that this would also return results where Victoria appears within the field, not necessary at the beginning of an entry.